# VPC endpont service using NLB of EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc-endpoint

We were able to create a endpoint service using the NLB created as part of an existing EKS deployment.    An endpoint connection is also created for this service in another vpc. The state of the connection is also available state.

However, the connections are getting timed out.  What should be done at NLB side to accept connections from the consumer vpc network

Both the endpoint service and endpoint connection are created in the same aws account